# Vue js Laravel - Axios making Multiple ( 2 ) Requests when changing pages , Category and Subcategory

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-router, watch

I'm building an application with **Vue** on the frontend and **Laravel** PHP on the backend. Its a single page app (SPA).

When changing pages, sometimes - *not always* - **axios** makes two requests for the same page. I'm having trouble figure it out what is happening.

When the link changes I have two watchers, one for the top category and another for the sub-category. They trigger the created () hook that calls the loadData method.

If I change the main category and sub category ( Example: from 1/5 to 2/31 ), the loadData method is called two time. How can I fix this ?

Google Network Tab (The **.json** request does not represent the same type of page that I'm referring above, only the numbers ) :
[image]

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
    import Form from 'vform'

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                products: {
                    cat : {} , 
                    products : []
                },
                productsShow: '',
                quickSearchQuery: '',
                loadeddata : false,
            }
        },

        methods: {
            loadMore () {
                this.productsShow += 21
            },
            loadData () {
                if ( this.$route.params.sub_id ) {
                    axios.get('/api/cat/' + this.$route.params.cat_id + '/' + this.$route.params.sub_id).then(response => { 
                    this.products = response.data 
                    this.productsShow = 21
                    this.loadeddata = true
                    }).catch(error => {
                        if (error.response.status === 404) {
                            this.$router.push('/404');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    axios.get('/api/cat/' + this.$route.params.cat_id ).then(response => { 
                    this.products = response.data 
                    this.productsShow = 21
                    this.loadeddata = true
                    }).catch(error => {
                        if (error.response.status === 404) {
                            this.$router.push('/404');
                        }
                    });
                }

            },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters({locale: 'lang/locale', locales: 'lang/locales' , user: 'auth/user'}),

            filteredRecords () {
                let data = this.products.products
                data = data.filter( ( row ) => {
                    return Object.keys( row ).some( ( key ) => {
                        return String( row[key] ).toLowerCase().indexOf(this.quickSearchQuery.toLowerCase()) > -1
                    })
                })
                return data
            }

        },
        created() {
            this.loadData()
        },
        watch: {
            '$route.params.cat_id': function (cat_id) {
                this.quickSearchQuery = ''
                this.loadData()

            },
            '$route.params.sub_id': function (sub_id) {
                this.quickSearchQuery = ''
                this.loadData()

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I found the pattern. If I stay in the same category only its called one time, ``'$route.params.cat_id': function (cat_id)`` , if I change the main category its called two times ``'$route.params.cat_id': function (cat_id)`` + ``'$route.params.sub_id': function (sub_id)``

Comment: How can I resolve this ? :/

Answer (score 0):

So I see that you figured the issue by yourself.

To fix that, you can delay the loadData function (kind of debounce on the tail) so if it's being called multiple times in less than X (300ms?) then only the last execution will run.

try:

```
loadData () {

   clearTimeout(this.loadDataTimeout);

   this.loadDataTimeout = setTimeout(()=> {

       //The rest of the loadData function should be placed here

    },300);

}
```

Comment: I dont want to tacle the problem that way :/ Already thought that.

Comment: Resolved : ``watch: {
    '$route.params': function (cat_id, sub_id) {
    this.quickSearchQuery = ''
    this.loadData()
},``

Comment: huh nice, I don't understand why it should work :0. the event should be triggered twice as same as the first implementation. interesting

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :

```
watch: {
    '$route.params': function (cat_id, sub_id) {
    this.quickSearchQuery = ''
    this.loadData()
},
```

[image]